# Do I need do add "over" after "come" in the following sentence?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> I couldn't sleep, so I thought I'd come (over) and chat with you for a bit'.

The person who's speaking went to another person's door. Do I need to add "over"? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Over" isn't necessary for the sentence to be grammatical and make sense, but it adds the idea that some distance, however small, is involved: perhaps merely crossing an aisle in an airplane, or from one wing of a college dormitory to another, or across town in a cab.